# Google Apps script HTML Service Input Form, Data not Recorded in Sheet from Other Users

Tags: html, google-apps-script, permissions, google-sheets

I have created a Form in HTML UI Service , its working fine when i submit the data. But when ever, any other user from the domain submits a record it is not recorded .I have changed the permission of backend spreadsheet to 'People who have the link can view'. Still the response is not recorded when a different user submits . Please assist possible correction

Comment: How did you deploy your app?  As user accessing the app?

Comment: yes , Execute the app as: User accessing the app.

Comment: then your app is not able to write to the spreadsheet... it needs to have write access.

Comment: OK got the error with try catch : Exception: Couldn't open document with id 0Hf7--HdFdkNW9NUGUtalhjd1ZWNXYwcXJ6ZkE: You do not have permissions to access the requested document.

Comment: see answer below with a possible workaround.

Comment: what are the permissions i need to set when i deploy the application. I am concerned about the Secutity

Comment: As mentioned in my answer the permission should be "anyone with the link can edit" or ,if you know who will use it grant access to specific users. The link will not be directly shown but still it's (relatively easily) hackable... The workaround with the 2cond app as service is completely safe and therefor far better.

Answer (score 0):

Since you set the permission of the spreadsheet to "anyone with the link can view" and that your app is running as the "user accessing the app" the app can't write anything in the spreadsheet. That's how it works.

If you don't want to change the SS authorizations you'll have to use some workaround to write data to this SS.

One possible way is to use a second app that runs as a service and that receives data from your webapp and write it back to the SS. This service would be running as "you" of course.

If you don't know how to go through this feel free to ask (and explain how much data you have to write) and I could show an example.

Comment: Thanks a lot .Appreciate your time